# Can I run Python in Sublime Text 2 on a Windows 7 machine that doesn't have python installed?

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext2, windows-7-x64

I highly doubt this is possible, but...

Sysadmin's worst nightmare; I don't have admin privilages at work. I have ST2 as a portable app, but building a python script doesn't work because Python isn't installed.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: How does one `build` a python script?  You can certainly write one - you just can't run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Portable Python on a USB stick.

http://portablepython.com/